# install kernel modules on ubuntu 16.04 ( no /lib/modules )

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, kernel-module

I have several Ubuntu 16.04 machines without /lib/modules directory, and if the result of lsmod is :

```
root@bla:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
xfs                   970752  1
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
```

With is pretty minimal. I need a whole lot more module. ( At least ip_table)

I'm not sure what is the procedure to install new modules. I can't use insmod, as I have nothing to point it at.

Edit:
What I wanna see:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-258:~$ modinfo ip_tables
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko
description:    IPv4 packet filter
author:         Netfilter Core Team <coreteam@netfilter.org>
license:        GPL
srcversion:     89FE8FA5C005273382ED2E6
depends:        x_tables
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-63-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

What I see:

```
root@strei2:~# modinfo ip_tables
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modinfo: ERROR: Module alias ip_tables not found.
```

What I've try:

- insmod: But the machine has no /lib/modules directory
- apt-get install ip_tables, but this module ( or any other, for what I could see ) are not in the repo.

  ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-333:~$ sudo apt-get install  ip_tables ==> package not found.

EDIT: I don't need/want to install the iptables user-space software. The underscore in ip_tables is not a typo.

Why I'm doing that:
I get the error:

```
FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic\niptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Haven't you got `apt-get`?

Comment: I do, but can you apt-get install module that way?

Comment: Drivers, etc are part of the repository. Installers can load modules as well as program suites.

Comment: That's great news. But could you be a tad more specific. See my edit

Comment: The package is `iptables` (no underscore) and it's in the 16.04 repository. Both `synaptic` (GUI) and `aptitude` (terminal) are useful for searching the repositories.

Comment: I'm aware of the existence of the iptables packages. I knew mentioning ip_tables was a bad idea and would confuse people :) 
iptables is a user-space software. I need to install the ip_tables kernel space module. Other kernel-module I need to install: libiscsi , x_tables , nf_nat_ftp

Comment: I think you are reaching the limit of my knowledge in this area. I can't understand why you have so few modules, though I've never installed a non-GUI version (is this what you have?). Did anything go wrong during installation? Does `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` help? Maybe it's time to grasp the nettle and re-install: you don't need to delete anything - with the right options you should be able to install over the top, which may lose some customised settings, but all the packages will be either preserved or updated.

Comment: Yeah, It's a weird setup. It's a server, so no GUI at all. I get that machine from a cloud provider. Their service is in Beta.